# Is "constringence" a word?

Tags: terminology, is-it-a-word

I would like to express, in one word, the tendency to concentrate excessively rather than disperse. This is applied in a sentence where I describe a set of data, which has too much focus on one aspect and miss out on other aspects.

For this I use the word "constringences".

> The results collected and presented earlier are limited by ambiguities, paradoxes and constringences.

However, it seems some dictionaries do not know *constringence*, while others do. So is it a word or isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for answers so far.
+ how does constringence differ from constriction? Should I not used the latter in my case?

Comment: Assuming the fault is with the data collector rather than the data themselves, I would use a different word entirely: *myopia*.

Comment: I think you could just use the word focus instead, but it would be best then to change the other words to singular also.

Comment: @Julia: yes, focus is good. But that would rather be "excessive focus" in this case. As kiamlaluno said, constringence belongs to a specific technical context. So for now I used constriction instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of five dictionaries I can consult, only the *Collins English Dictionary* reports that word.

> [physics] inverse of the dispersive
>     power of a medium

I would say it's a word, but it is used in a specific, technical context.

Comment: Cheers :) I've then used "constriction" instead, although I'm not very happy with the word either.

Answer (score 3):

The OED says the noun from *constringent* is *constringency*.  On the other hand, your specialised sense doesn't really fit, as *constringent* there means 'causing constriction'.

I don't think it's a normal word, but there's no reason not to use it as a specialised term, as long you define it at the first use.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the term, so if I *did* come across it, I'd appreciate a definition at first use, as you advise. But on checking, it seems to be a standard term in physics/optics for the Abbe/V-number (again, not previously known to me), so I suppose if you were writing in that context you could assume your readers should know the word. Anyway, as you say, it doesn't really seem to fit OP's context. I think he'd do better to use a more common word such as **constraints**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a word. It doesn't have to be in every dictionary for it to be considered a word. Here's one entry from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/constringence) (using Collins English Dictionary as its source):

> **constringence**  (kənˈstrɪndʒəns)
>   ***— n***
>   *physics*  inverse of the dispersive power of a medium

It's also defined in [TheFreeDictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/constringence), and in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbe_number) and [Britannica](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/134399/constringence) encyclopaedias with a very specific meaning with optics.

None of these suggest a metaphoric dispersion of data. Therefore I'd hesitate in using the term with anything but these exact meanings, and only for audiences who can be expected to know the term.